# Validating radio button before continuing with PHP

Tags: php, validation, radio-button

I'm trying to write a validation that checks to see if any of the radio selections have actually been selected before continuing to the next page... This is what I have so far, with my attempt at a validation [code on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5nNCPDsk)

I'm only using the `header('Location: index.php');` to show that it worked (which it hasn't yet). If nothing has been selected, I want it to display a message like "Please select crust and size before continuing." and stay on the same page. If an item is selected, it should take the user to the next page, cheese.php

What do I need to change in order for this validation to work?

Comment: Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @EdCottrell   
Search, and research: 2+ hours spent googling and searching. Check.
Write a title that summarizes the specific problem: Check.
Introduce the problem before you post any code: Info first, then code, Check.
Help others reproduce the problem: code attached. Check
Include all relevant tags: php,radio,validation. Check
Proof-read before posting!:no typos. Check
Post the question and respond to feedback: Posted and responding to feedback. Check and check.
Look for help asking for help: How can I help you, help me? (check)

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed, for this reason: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)